# How to get access the element in code behind, which is declared inside a DataTemplate in xaml page in Xamarin.Foms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to access the Entry declared in a DataTemplate which is actually in a ItemTemplate in ListView, through a button click.

```
<StackLayout>

    <Button Text="GetEntryTemplate" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>

    <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Customer}">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>

                <ViewCell>

                    <Entry Text="Xamarin"/>

                </ViewCell>

            </DataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>

</StackLayout>


    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var loadedTemplate = listView.ItemTemplate.CreateContent();
        var view = ((loadedTemplate as ViewCell).View as Entry).Text;            
    }
```

I have tried CreateContent(), which actually does not shows the run time changes.

Can  someone help me out of this. In short I need to access the Existing Entry instance(Declared inside DataTemplate) text through the Button click.

Comment: I think that with a little bit of googling you could find a solution. From my experience with Windows Forms something like this should work - https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/129774/find-entry-control-inside-the-listview-viewcell But it seems that there are other approaches which may be better in the context of Xamarin.

Comment: It sounds like an [XY-Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. What do you need this for? Of course the run-time changes are not reflected, since you are creating a **new** instance of the template and not accessing the existing instances.

Comment: List view has collections of view cells. So which entry exactly you want to reference: first one, selected one, one that user taped?

Comment: Hi @Arvis, I have only one Item in my collection. So I have one Entry. And I need to access this Entry text from code behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Data-Binding to set and get the text of the entry.

> in xaml

```
<StackLayout>

    <Button Text="GetEntryTemplate" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>

    <ListView x:Name="listView">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>

                <ViewCell>

                    <Entry TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Content,Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                </ViewCell>

            </DataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>

</StackLayout>
```

> in your code behind

create a mode (for example my model called Data)

```
public class Data
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

And in contentPage

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public ObservableCollection<Data> MySource { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = this;



        MySource = new ObservableCollection<Data>()
        {
          new Data() {Content="Entry_1" },
        };

        listView.ItemsSource = MySource;

    }



    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DisplayAlert("title", MySource[0].Content, "cancel");

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to choose another approach.

Why don't you use `Binding` for your `Entry` in `ListView`? If you are new to Xamarin, I would recommend you to read about MVVM pattern: [link to MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm).

You could add param like `EntryText` in your `Customer` class and get value from your ViewModel, where you will create a binded param.

Answer (score -1):

Better approach would be to use view model with data binding.

But if you had to get reference to control element itself you can do this way
(items source must have at least one item in collection, added item explicitly in xaml for example):

```
<Button Text="GetEntryTemplate" Clicked="Button_OnClicked"/>

<ListView x:Name="listView">

    <ListView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>my customer</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </ListView.ItemsSource>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Entry x:Name="cellEntry" Text="Xamarin"/>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cell = listView.TemplatedItems.FirstOrDefault();
    var entry = (Entry)cell.FindByName("cellEntry");
    DisplayAlert("My Entry", entry.Text, "Close");
}
```

Comment: It is unwise to set the property `name` in listview when you use `DataTemplate`.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT that is not unwise but more like non-effective approach but that's only straight answer to OP question: `How to access the Entry instance through the Button click?`.